# Understanding the representation of inifinite lists as the limit of partial lists in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, types, infinite

I was going through [this](https://hackhands.com/non-strict-semantics-haskell/) article which explains Haskell's non-strict semantics. I understood till the author starts talking about *Partial and Infinite Lists* in Haskell.

The author says :-

> The idea is that an infinite list is to be understood as a *limit* of partial lists.

---

And after that, the author goes on to explain the execution of the expression :-

`filter (< 3) [1..]`

<del>The result kinda goes against my intuition of my expected output. I thought the answer would be simply the list :- `[1, 2]`. But, nope!!.</del> While the authors explain is sufficient to understand the execution process and how we get the final result, it doesn't explain **why** it works like so.

So, my question is **why** are infinite lists represented as the limit of a bunch of partial lists? Can someone explain this without digging too deep into complex mathematical jargon?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you think that the result would be `[1, 2]`? `filter` has no way of knowing when to stop checking for the elements... for example consider that: `cycle [1..N]` contains an infinite number of `1`s and `2`s but if you only look at a finite prefix it looks very similar to `[1..]` and you can choose `N` as big as you want.

Comment: Oh yes. I'm sorry, I got very confused between `filter` and `takewhile`. I'm very new to haskell. Sorry for this stupid stupid confusion. 
I'll edit the question now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To put things simply, the Haskell compiler is not magic, however magical it may sometimes appear. While certain sorts of expressions may seem extremely declarative compared to other programming languages, Haskell’s evaluation semantics are actually remarkably simple.

For this reason, in the example you mention, `filter (< 3) [1..]`, GHC does not “know” anything about the *meaning* of the above expression. While it is obvious to a human than there will never be any elements after `2` that satisfy the `(< 3)` predicate, there is no reason that `filter` can be aware that there won’t *eventually* be some element that does. For this reason, attempting to evaluate anything other than the first two elements of the resulting list will produce an infinite loop.

This is the idea behind the explanation that infinite lists in Haskell are really just “limits”. A true analytical system can work with infinite lists, and it can make assertions about *all* of their elements. One can trivially prove, mathematically, that the infinite list represented by the Haskell expression `[1..]` only contains two elements that are less than 3, but Haskell does not have any such analytical capabilities—it’s just a functional programming language.

Using the analog to a mathematical limit, we can say that evaluating `[1..]` approaches the infinite list given an infinite amount of time and space, but without that, it’s just a computation—a promise that we can always produce more elements if we want, but unlike a mathematical infinite set, it is not some high level description of a truly infinite set of elements. It’s just a finite set of elements with an arbitrary size and a description of how to obtain more.